# Tkinter: Updating Labels mid-loop

Tags: python, while-loop, tkinter

I would like to update a Label in my GUI to be a sort of progress bar, display how complete a data transfer is.

Everywhere I look, people say  to use the `textvariable` option of Label and then to set the string and the label updates. This does not work for me. The label updates at the end of the data collection loop. I don't know too much about programming in depth but I imagine that Python is not refreshing Tkinter until after it is finished with the data collection loop rather than mid loop.

Here's the data collection loop:

```
def getdata(self, filename):
    data=[]
    count=0
    percentage=0
    self.ser.write('$get\r\n')
    total=int(self.ser.readline().split()[0])
    line=self.ser.readline()
    while line != '':
        data.append(line)
        count+= 1
        if percentage != str(round(float(count)/total,2)):
            menu.percentage.set(str(round(float(count)/total,2)*100)+'% Completed')

            #^^^menu.percentage is the textvariable of the Label I want updated^^^#

            print str(round(float(count)/total,2)*100)+'% Completed'
        percentage = str(round(float(count)/total,2))
        line=self.ser.readline()       
    outfile=open(filename, 'w')
    outfile.writelines(data)
```

My question is: Is there some sort of command that will update the Label in the GUI in realtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tkinter: How do widgets update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781286/tkinter-how-do-widgets-update)

Comment: I don't really think that's a good dupe; that question admits several solutions and is really background, whereas this one has one good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is to call `update_idletasks`. This works because widget updating is handled as an *idle task*. These normally get executed by the event loop but you can cause them to be called vial `update_idletasks`.

For a little more background, see the answers to the question [How do widgets update in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781286/tkinter-how-do-widgets-update), or just search for `update_idletasks` on this site.