# python ttk: force screen update

Tags: python, ttk

How can I force ttk to update the screen?  I'm running a long loop and would like to display some interim results, but ttk waits until it finishes the loop to update the screen.

I tried inserting sleep and after calls in the loop, but that didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tkinter: Updating Labels mid-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125398/tkinter-updating-labels-mid-loop)

Comment: update_idletasks() appears to be the answer, at least for me.  That question was about update_idletasks() not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update_idletasks() appears to be the answer.  For example adding

```
 relevant_widget.update_idletasks()
```

in the loop works.